# Capture moving images with multiple webcams

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, capture

I am trying to capture images when there is any movement involved using 2 webcams, each one pointing at different angles. I started to try `motion` but I am starting to believe is only for a single webcam. Is it for multiple? and if not, what other terminal or GUI app is there to capture only when movement is involved from 2 or more webcams?

Comment: It looks like http://www.zoneminder.com/ does what you want, but I haven't used it at all.

Comment: Tried it right now. User friendliness was left for dead in a desert somewhere... at least it needs a lot of setup for a webcam capturing system. I need more time to configure everything. Looking for an easier solution before jumping towards that direction.

Comment: +1 AbrahamVanHelpsing. I was configuring the whole thing up until one of the webcams did not work. Luckly thanks to you I found something in motion for multiple webcams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying out the suggestion from AbrahamVanHelpsing was good. `Zoneminder` which already comes in Ubuntu did work but after several minutes of configuration it was set up. Bad thing is, it did not detect one of the webcams, it only threw a black screen when probing it. Anyway it is recommended to use this one as it is more robust that motion.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install zoneminder`. Configuration information is in their [website](http://www.zoneminder.com/documentation).

But after messing around with it I went back to motion because I felt it was strange that a app called MOTION did not have an option for multiple webcams. I was right.

Just in case, to install motion is as easy as `sudo apt-get install motion`

Now in the `/etc/motion/motion.conf` file the LAST options are for multiple webcams:

```
##############################################################
# Thread config files - One for each camera.
# Except if only one camera - You only need this config file.
# If you have more than one camera you MUST define one thread
# config file for each camera in addition to this config file.
##############################################################

# Remember: If you have more than one camera you must have one
# thread file for each camera. E.g. 2 cameras requires 3 files:
# This motion.conf file AND thread1.conf and thread2.conf.
# Only put the options that are unique to each camera in the
# thread config files. 
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread1.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread2.conf    
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread3.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread4.conf
```

So I edited the last lines so it looked like this:

```
thread /etc/motion/thread1.conf
thread /etc/motion/thread2.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread3.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread4.conf
```

Note that I changed the folder location since there is no `thread.conf` files in `/usr/local/etc`. They are found in the same place as `motion.conf`.

After that I had to go to each `thread.conf` file and change it to what I needed. There are 3 options that should be edited:

**videodevice** - Should be set to the **/dev** your webcam is using. To find out simply type `find /dev -name video*` in the terminal. It should show you the webcams you have. In my case it was video0 and video1.

**input** - This should be set to **8** if you are going to use a webcam, else use **1** if you are using a TV Card.

**target_dir** - It should be set to where you want the captured images to go.

Lastly all other options are in the `motion.conf` file like web server, amount of capture images when movement is detected, etc..

After that run motion with sudo `sudo motion` to start capturing.